# How to add breakpoints to .feature files

Tags: debugging, automation, cucumber, bdd

As a developer
I want to put breakpoint(s) in feature files
So that I can debug a feature/scenario/step

Have any of you implemented this functionality with Behave or Cucumber?

Comment: Write a step for breakpoint.

Answer (score 3):

You can not put breakpoints to `.feature` files, because it is a plain text files. Instead you can put breakpoints inside test-steps which implement your BDD steps.

**Example**
`When I click button "save"
Then saved page opened`

You need to go inside that step and see something like that:
`public void iClickButton(String buttonName) {
     getButtonByName(buttonName).click();
}`

You can put breakpoint inside method `iClickButton` and debug it. 
That is how you can debug execution in BDD style.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say I've ever been able to put breakpoints in feature files.  Instead, I put them inside the step files so when that step runs, you can verify it did its job.  It's a lot of switching back and forth between feature and step files, but it works

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that in 2018 feature files are used by a lot more than Behave or Cucumber [i.e. Codeception for PHP]. "Gherkin" is supposed to be a business readable DSL and the concept of a "breakpoint" really doesn't apply in that domain. I'd say it's definitionally impossible to put a break point in a Gherkin feature file. You could certainly do that if you want, go for it, but there isn't a standard way of doing it, and it's possible you'd be confusing things in a large organization or team.

Comment: It's been that way for a long time, not just in 2018. The Given, When, Then syntax was created by @tastapod and Chris Matts in 2003 and predates both Cucumber and the name "Gherkin" (which is named after it, being a small, pickled cucumber). Having said that, we've always been able to put breakpoints in the related code as suggested in the other answer, and some IDEs do support breakpoints on the feature files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add debug in step definition not in feature file

Now, You are running it by maven command like:

> mvn clean install

But you need to run it using junit or testng.

Put an debug point in your step defination and run the project as junit/testng in debug section

OR

If you still need to run it using maven you can try below parameter in maven command

```
-Dmaven.surefire.debug test -DforkCount=0 test
```